Docker Build Fails on Azure DevOps (2022) with npm login 401 Error
I recently upgraded to Azure DevOps Server 2022, and now my Docker build pipelines are failing with a 401 Unauthorized error during the npm login step. The build uses an npm feed hosted in Azure DevOps.
Environment Details:
Build Agent: Self-hosted Ubuntu VM located in Azure.
npm Feed: Hosted on Azure DevOps Server (TFS).
Dockerfile: Contains steps to install npm packages using the npm feed.
Steps Taken:
Created a new Personal Access Token (PAT) with full access.
Updated the .npmrc file in the project.
.npmrc File:
ini
@mmmmmm:registry=http://XX.xx.xx.xx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/RotemsNPMFeed/npm/registry/
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
always-auth=true

//xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/RotemsNPMFeed/npm/registry/:username=DefaultCollection
//xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/RotemsNPMFeed/npm/registry/:_password=1234567899999999999999999999
//xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/RotemsNPMFeed/npm/registry/:email=npm@example.com

Dockerfile:
FROM mhart/alpine-node:14.15.5

ARG Version=1.0.0
ARG BuildConfiguration=prod
ARG NPM_TOKEN
ARG KENDO_UI_LICENSE

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN echo "{ \"version\" : \"$Version\" }" > version.json

COPY server-build.npmrc .npmrc
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npx kendo-ui-license activate
COPY . .
RUN npm run lint
RUN npm run test
RUN npm rebuild sass
RUN npm run build:$BuildConfiguration
RUN npm prune --production

FROM arm32v7/nginx:1.21.3
ARG Version=1.0.0
COPY --from=0 /usr/src/app/nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY --from=0 /usr/src/app/dist/rotem5-touch/ .
COPY --from=0 /usr/src/app/version.json .
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=5s --retries=3 CMD service nginx status > /dev/null 2>&1

Build Command:
docker build --no-cache -f $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/rotem5-touch/Dockerfile.arm32v7 \
  --label "build-version=$(Build.BuildNumber)" \
  --label "git-hash=$(Build.SourceVersion)" \
  --build-arg Version=$(Build.BuildNumber) \
  --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=$(NPM_TOKEN) \
  --build-arg KENDO_UI_LICENSE=$(KENDO_UI_LICENSE) \
  -t rotem5containerregistry.azurecr.io/arm32v7/r5-touch-app:$(Build.BuildNumber) \
  $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/rotem5-touch

What I've Tried:
Created a new PAT with full access and updated the _password field in .npmrc.
Ensured the always-auth=true setting is present in .npmrc.
Verified that the npm feed URL is correct.
Tried different combinations of http and https in the .npmrc.
Issue Observed:
The build fails with a 401 Unauthorized error during the npm install step, despite using a valid PAT and correctly configured .npmrc.
Questions:
Is there any additional configuration needed for .npmrc when using an npm feed hosted on Azure DevOps Server 2022?
Does the self-hosted Ubuntu agent require specific environment settings for authentication?
Could the issue be related to the upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2022?
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

As mentioned in the answer, when connecting your npm project to Azure Artifacts feed from a non-Windows environment, you need to convert your PAT to be a Base 64 encoded token.  @sharh

You seemed did not convert your PAT to be a Base 64 encoded token.
When on Linux machines, you need to convert your PAT to be a Base 64 encoded token. Then copy the Base 64 encoded token into the .npmrc file as the value of _password.
You can run the following command to convert PAT to be a Base 64 encoded token on Linux machines.
echo -n "YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" | base64

Then copy and paste the output Base 64 encoded token into the .npmrc file.
For more details, you can see the documentation "Connect your npm project to Azure Artifacts".


